# Execute php file from another php

Tags: php

I want to call a PHP file that starts like

```
<?php
function connection () {
   //Statements
}
```

I call from the PHP like this:

```
<?php
exec ('/opt/lampp/htdocs/stuff/name.php');
?>
```

I get:

```
line1-> cannot open ?: No such file
line 3 //Connection: not found
line 4 Syntax errror: "("
```

Why doesn't this correctly execute the name.php file?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

It's trying to run it as a shell script, which interprets your `<?php` token as bash, which is a syntax error.  Just use `include()` or one of its friends:

For example, in `a.php` put:

```
<?php
print "one";
include 'b.php';
print "three";
?>
```

In `b.php` put:

```
<?php
print "two";
?>
```

Prints:

```
eric@dev ~ $ php a.php
onetwothree
```

Comment: My page seems to be caching the result when I include, so when I rerun the file, it doesn't take as long.

Comment: Can't this cause problems if both PHP files are using the same variable names?

Comment: Turns out you don't need to put include statements at the beginning of your document, you can put them where needed throughout your file.

Answer (score 18):

exec is shelling to the operating system, and unless the OS has some special way of knowing how to execute a file, then it's going to default to treating it as a shell script or similar.
In this case, it has no idea how to run your php file.
If this script absolutely has to be executed from a shell, then either execute php passing the filename as a parameter, e.g

```
exec ('/usr/local/bin/php -f /opt/lampp/htdocs/.../name.php)') ;
```

or use the punct at the top of your php script

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php ... ?>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I also tried exec('/usr/... -f /oopt.../name.php)' and it either worked. finally I use include() and it works. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you're trying to execute the PHP code directly in your shell. Your shell doesn't speak PHP, so it interprets your PHP code as though it's in your shell's native language, as though you had literally run `<?php` at the command line.

Shell scripts usually start with a "shebang" line that tells the shell what program to use to interpret the file. Begin your file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
//Connection
function connection () {
```

Besides that, the string you're passing to `exec` doesn't make any sense. It starts with a slash all by itself, it uses too many periods in the path, and it has a stray right parenthesis.

Copy the contents of the command string and paste them at your command line. If it doesn't run there, then `exec` probably won't be able to run it, either.

Another option is to change the command you execute. Instead of running the script directly, run `php` and pass your script as an argument. Then you shouldn't need the shebang line.

```
exec('php name.php');
```

Comment: is there any alternate if a server has disabled exec() function

Comment: That's a question you should [ask on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), @Lord_linus.

Answer (score 4):

This came across while working on a project on linux platform.

```
exec('wget http://<url to the php script>)
```

This runs as if you run the script from browser.

Comment: Why are people voting this down?  Is there a reason why you shouldn't do it this way?

Comment: Because you are fetching the script via http instead of just directly executing it. That's roundabout and insecure.