# php: Execute php file from another php file with parameters

Tags: php, mysql, php-include

**Details:** I have a php file that runs some sql and retrieve a list of information.  I run through a loop of that information and want to call another php page and pass it some parameters from the data I am looping through.

**Question:** How do I execute another php page from within my php?

**What I Have Tried:** This is the php code that should be calling the second php page (the while loop should be calling the simplepush.php page for each result I get):

```
<?php
require_once "../database/config.php";
header("Content-type: application/json");
$sql = "SELECT user_ip_address FROM ft_users";
$res = mssql_query($sql);
if (mssql_num_rows($res)) {

    while ($op = mssql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        exec('simplepush.php?token = ' . $op . '');
        $arr[] = $op;
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);

    //$op = mssql_fetch_assoc($res);
    //$op['response'] = 200;
} else {
    http_response_code(420);
    $op = array(
        'response' => 420
    );
    echo json_encode($op);
}

mssql_close();
?>
```

I have tried the following:

```
include ('simplepush.php?token = '.$op.'');
exec ('simplepush.php?token = '.$op.'');
require ('simplepush.php?token = '.$op.'');
shell_exec ('simplepush.php?token = '.$op.'');
```

Comment: did you try this: `include ('simplepush.php?token = '.$op);` what result you get?

Comment: When I use that the code in my other php file does not get executed.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450696/execute-a-php-script-from-another-php-script) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841093/execute-php-file-from-another-php) one

Comment: I've actually already seen those links and none of those options are working.  You can see where I put I have tried the following: it shows all of those options except for the shell_exec one and it does not work.

Comment: can you share simplepush.php? maybe your php code is not working

Comment: You need to reconsider how you are trying to achieve your requirement. I suggest you to create function in the second php file , then include and then call it from your main php. Anyway, try this to see what is happening after you execute
`$result = exec('simplepush.php?token = ' . $op . '');` 
`var_dump($result);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
include ('simplepush.php');
```

Now `$op` will be available in `simplepush.php`.  Consider this example:

```
//index.php
while ($op = mssql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    include ('simplepush.php');
    $arr[] = $op;
}

//simplepush.php
print_r($op);
```

The contents of `$op` will be output each time through the loop.

Comment: Great, it is now calling my other php file.  How do I get $op in my other php file, though.  I do not understand what you mean by renaming $token.  This is how I declare $token..... $deviceToken = trim(strip_tags($_REQUEST['token']));

Comment: I beginning to think I need to delete this :-(

Comment: I don't think you should.  This helped me get it working.  I changed my include statement to what you suggested and found a solution after using the print_r($op);