# PHP fopen on iis prob

Tags: php

I'm working on a Windows server with iis.

When i want to execute a php file it gives me the error:

> Warning: fopen(path/script.php): failed to open stream: Permission
>   denied in C:\path\path\path\script.php on line 71 Error opening

This is the code in the php file:

```
$var = fopen ($strFileName, 'w');   if(!$var) die(' Error opening');
```

Comment: You probably need to use a full pathname in `$strFileName`, to create the file in the appropriate folder that the webserver username has permission for.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few things that will help. First check your open_basedir restriction settings in your php installation .ini file.

open_basedir either needs to be set to the path that you want php to have file operation access to or you can set it to none to have no limitation.

Another thing to check is your environment variables on the machine that the code is being run on. Under environment variables find the entry for Path. Click edit and copy and paste what is in the value field to notepad. You want to make sure there is an entry that leads to your php installation folder as well as an entry that leads to where the code lives.

Example: C:\PHP;C:\websites;

Additionally, you will want to give the IIS User account full access to the location where your php code and the files you want to open exist.

Answer (score 0):

what you want is Execute php file from another php, but your code is wrong because your trying to write to script.php in place of executing it   [[Execute php file from another php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841093/execute-php-file-from-another-php][1]) this answer is already answered in the link ;).